# SVG masked vertical lines are not visible

Tags: svg, svg.js

In this example I made using SVG.js line is not visible, while line2 is. The difference is that line is perfectly vertical while line2 is not. Can you pls help me?

```
W=400;
H=400;
s = SVG('mySvg');
s.rect(W,H).fill('#f00')

let maskRect = s.rect(W-20,H-20).move(10,10);
maskRect.attr({
stroke: '#fff',
'strokeWidth': 0,
fill: '#fff'
});
let mask = s.mask().add(maskRect);

//not visible ???
let line = s.line(10,0,10,H);
line.stroke({color: '#0', width:4});
line.maskWith(mask)

//visible
let line2 = s.line(20,0,22,H);
line2.stroke({color: '#0', width:4});
line2.maskWith(mask)
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwyJxR
In case this is browser related, I am using Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) on Windows 10

Comment: Checked with SVG.js developers. This seems to be related directly to the way the browser renders the content.

Comment: Got the same issue, do you get a solution, bro?

Comment: I  see this , it may help https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=570432

Answer (score 0):

maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" is required.

Try this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-sun-dh95qp?file=/index.html

[image]